# Error converting C++ to rust - Issue with exponent adjustment in standardform

Tags: c++, math, rust

I'm currently trying to convert some old C++ code to Rust and I'm encountering an error while implementing the `StandardForm` class. In the original C++ code, the class  represents a number in standard form, with a mantissa and an exponent.

Here's the relevant C++ code:

```cpp
class StandardForm /* : public deathsdoor::nodes::TreeNode<deathsdoor::math::NodeType>*/ {
        private:
            double num = 1;
            int power = 1;
            bool isInValidRange() const noexcept{
                return (num >= 1 && num <= 10) || (num >= -10 && num <= -1);
            }
            //...
          public :
              StandardForm(const double& n,const int& pow) noexcept: TreeNode(NodeType::StandardFormNumber){
                // this had to be done for some reason
                if(isInValidRange()){
                    setPower(pow);
                    setNum(n);
                }
                else{
                    setNum(n);
                    setPower(pow);
                }
            }  

            void setNum(const double& num) noexcept{
                this->num = num;

                if (isInValidRange()) return;

                double absNumber = std::abs(num);
                int logZehn = std::ceil(std::log10(absNumber));
                this->num /= std::pow(10, logZehn);
                this->power = logZehn;

                if (this->num < 0) this->num = -this->num;

                if(this->num > 0 && this->num < 1) {
                    this->num *= 10;
                    this->power -= 1;
                }
            }

            void setPower(const int& power) noexcept{
                this->power = power;
            }
}
            //...
```

And here's my attempt at translating it to Rust:

```rust
/// Represents a number in standard form.
///
/// The `Standardform` struct holds the significand (mantissa) of the number
/// and an exponent that determines the power of 10 by which the significand should be multiplied.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct StandardForm {
    mantissa: f64,
    exponent: i8,
}

impl StandardForm {
    /// Creates a new instance of StandardForm with the given mantissa and exponent
    pub fn new(mantissa: f64, exponent: i8) -> Self {
        let mut instance = Self { mantissa, exponent };
        instance.adjust();
        instance
    }

    fn in_range(&self) -> bool {
        (self.mantissa >= 1.0 && self.mantissa <= 10.0)
            || (self.mantissa >= -10.0 && self.mantissa <= -1.0)
    }

    fn adjust(&mut self) {
        if self.in_range() {
            return;
        }

        let abs_number = f64::abs(self.mantissa);
        let log_zehn = f64::ceil(f64::log10(abs_number));
        self.mantissa /= f64::powf(10.0, log_zehn);
        self.exponent = log_zehn as i8;

        if self.mantissa < 0.0 {
            self.mantissa = -self.mantissa;
        }

        if self.mantissa > 0.0 && self.mantissa < 1.0 {
            self.mantissa *= 10.0;
            self.exponent -= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are some test cases that its failing (similar testcases in cpp are succeeding) :

```rust
#[test]
fn test_normalize_with_invalid_range() {
    let mut sf = StandardForm::new(20.0, 3);
    sf.adjust();
    assert_eq!(sf.mantissa, 2.0);
    assert_eq!(sf.exponent, 4);
}

#[test]
fn test_normalize_with_small_mantissa() {
    let mut sf = StandardForm::new(-0.25, 2);
    sf.adjust();
    assert_eq!(sf.mantissa, -2.5);
    assert_eq!(sf.exponent, 1);
}

#[test]
fn test_normalize_with_large_negative_mantissa() {
    let mut sf = StandardForm::new(-750.0, 4);
    sf.adjust();
    assert_eq!(sf.mantissa, -7.5);
    assert_eq!(sf.exponent, 6);
}
```

I have tried changing the `valid_range` and also try changing the overall maths but nothing seems to be working.

I have a feeling this due to this line , as this condition had to be put in place for it to work , I tried a similar thing in rust but that too isnt working.

```cpp
// this had to be done for some reason
    if(isInValidRange()){
        setPower(pow);
        setNum(n);
    }
    else {
        setNum(n);
        setPower(pow);
    }
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong, and I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Srry stack overlow mobile changed it give me a minute

Comment: I have formatted everything correctly

Comment: No I have copied it from the computer and pasted it on the mobile , something about vscode + phone doesn't mix  and wait I'll update to fix the compile issue. also srry for the mistakes it's like almost the first time I've used stack overflow in forever

Comment: What do you think `if(mantissa < 0) { mantissa = -mantissa }` does and why do you expect `mantissa == -2.5` afterwards?

Comment: Why do you completely ignore the previous exponent in `adjust`?

Comment: In the C++ code, if the original values are not `inValidRange` you adjust the `num` then overwrite the `pow`, ignoring its original value, no?. In the Rust code, the exponent gets adjusted as well.

Comment: Oh no I just realised the conditional is a red herring because it runs on the default values doesn't it? Those should always be in valid range. However given the signature of the methods what do the C++ tests do in lieu of `adjust`?

Comment: At that moment that's what I did , as I found no better way to do so and over came the issues caused by that using the if else statement to set power and num is different orders in the constructor which for some reason worked , and in CPP adjust logic is placed in setNum which I realise now is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample function is

```rust
fn adjust(&mut self) {
        if self.in_range() || self.mantissa == 0.0 {
            return;
        }

        // means its things like 0.2323 not -700
        match self.mantissa > -1.0 && self.mantissa < 1.0 {
            true => while !self.in_range() {
                self.mantissa *= 10.0;
                self.exponent -= 1; 
            },
            false => while !self.in_range() {
                self.mantissa /= 10.0;
                self.exponent += 1; 
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the [crate](https://crates.io/crates/standardform) I made using this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this ever worked in C++, but it shouldn't have.

Your `adjust` function completely disregards the current value of `self.exponent` and replaces it with the exponent of `self.mantissa`. At no point of the calculation of the new `self.exponent` value do you ever read the current `self.exponent` value.

Regarding the other two tests: How should `mantissa` ever be `-2.5` if you explicitely normalize away negative values with this?

```rust
if self.mantissa < 0.0 {
    self.mantissa = -self.mantissa;
}
```

I feel like there is a `negative: bool` missing somewhere in your normalized data structure. Again, I have no idea how the C++ thing ever did anything reasonable.

To fix that, either adjust your tests or the behavior of your code.

This works:

```rust
/// Represents a number in standard form.
///
/// The `Standardform` struct holds the significand (mantissa) of the number
/// and an exponent that determines the power of 10 by which the significand should be multiplied.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct StandardForm {
    mantissa: f64,
    exponent: i8,
}

impl StandardForm {
    /// Creates a new instance of StandardForm with the given mantissa and exponent
    pub fn new(mantissa: f64, exponent: i8) -> Self {
        let mut instance = Self {
            mantissa,
            exponent,
        };
        instance.adjust();
        instance
    }

    fn in_range(&self) -> bool {
        (self.mantissa >= 1.0 && self.mantissa <= 10.0)
            || (self.mantissa >= -10.0 && self.mantissa <= -1.0)
    }

    fn adjust(&mut self) {
        if self.in_range() {
            return;
        }

        let abs_number = f64::abs(self.mantissa);
        let log_zehn = f64::ceil(f64::log10(abs_number));
        self.mantissa /= f64::powf(10.0, log_zehn);
        self.exponent += log_zehn as i8;

        if self.mantissa < 0.0 {
            self.mantissa = -self.mantissa;
        }

        if self.mantissa > 0.0 && self.mantissa < 1.0 {
            self.mantissa *= 10.0;
            self.exponent -= 1;
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_normalize_with_invalid_range() {
    let mut sf = StandardForm::new(20.0, 3);
    sf.adjust();
    assert_eq!(sf.mantissa, 2.0);
    assert_eq!(sf.exponent, 4);
}

#[test]
fn test_normalize_with_small_mantissa() {
    let mut sf = StandardForm::new(-0.25, 2);
    sf.adjust();
    assert_eq!(sf.mantissa, 2.5);
    assert_eq!(sf.exponent, 1);
}

#[test]
fn test_normalize_with_large_negative_mantissa() {
    let mut sf = StandardForm::new(-750.0, 4);
    sf.adjust();
    assert_eq!(sf.mantissa, 7.5);
    assert_eq!(sf.exponent, 6);
}
```

```
running 3 tests
test test_normalize_with_invalid_range ... ok
test test_normalize_with_large_negative_mantissa ... ok
test test_normalize_with_small_mantissa ... ok

test result: ok. 3 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.02s
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , tbn to this moment I have no clue how it that worked , only that it worked. Regarding : How should mantissa ever be -2.5 if you explicitely normalize away negative values with this?.. I noticed this but thought it best to post the exact conversion so no one answers oh remove the -mantissa , as at the moment only the c++ version worked at all.

Comment: Also this seems to work like magic , but is there a way to make it work with negative numbers eg -3*10^2 as those are common in maths. So that 3*10^-2 is 0.03 and -3*10^2 is -300 without adding more fields that complicate operations with the struct like +-*/ etc, if at all possible. Again thanks very much

Comment: Well to me it's obvious why the cpp version worked, it does something similar in a completely different way, I think in fact the all of the cpp code is just a big red herring. You  can't use the logic of a `setNum` and use it verbatim to write `adjust` both with different meanigs.

Comment: @cafce25 `setNum` might work, out of context, but the class constructor doesn't make much sense to me. It still doesn't accept negative numbers in the C++ version